# List<Attachment> Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: image, flutter, attachment

I have 3 button on which when the user clicks it they take a photo and the button change in the preview of the photo.And on longPress the picture gets removed and replaced by the first button. When I try to remove the photo I get the following error :

```
Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
E/flutter ( 4122): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:146:60)
E/flutter ( 4122): #1      _HomePageNoticeProblemState.removePicture.<anonymous closure> (package:flutterapperadauti/notice_a_problem/main_page.dart:117:23)
E/flutter ( 4122): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1233:30)
E/flutter ( 4122): #3      _HomePageNoticeProblemState.removePicture (package:flutterapperadauti/notice_a_problem/main_page.dart:113:5)
E/flutter ( 4122): #4      _HomePageNoticeProblemState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutterapperadauti/notice_a_problem/main_page.dart:509:23)
E/flutter ( 4122): #5      _InkResponseState._handleLongPress (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:805:25)
E/flutter ( 4122): #6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:865:61)
E/flutter ( 4122): #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 4122): #8      LongPressGestureRecognizer._checkLongPressStart (package:flutter/src/gestures/long_press.dart:304:7)
E/flutter ( 4122): #9      LongPressGestureRecognizer.didExceedDeadline (package:flutter/src/gestures/long_press.dart:253:5)
E/flutter ( 4122): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.didExceedDeadlineWithEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:501:5)
E/flutter ( 4122): #11     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:454:40)
E/flutter ( 4122): #12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter ( 4122): #13     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter ( 4122): #14     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter ( 4122): #15     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter ( 4122): #16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter ( 4122): #17     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter ( 4122): #18     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1003:23)
E/flutter ( 4122): #19     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter ( 4122): #20     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter ( 4122): #21     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter ( 4122): #22     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter ( 4122):
```

On this line:         `if(attachments[1] != null) {`

My list is of type attachments

my code for removing a picture:

```
void removePicture(int i) async {
setState(() {
  if(i==1) {
    attachments.removeAt(0);
    recordedImage1 = null;
    if(attachments[1] != null) {
      attachments[0] = attachments[1];
      recordedImage1 = recordedImage2;
    }
    if(attachments[2] != null) {
      attachments[1] = attachments[2];
      recordedImage2 = recordedImage3;
      recordedImage3 = null;
    }
  }
  if(i==2) {
    recordedImage2 = null;
    attachments.removeAt(1);
    if(attachments[2] != null) {
      attachments[1] = attachments[2];
      recordedImage2 = recordedImage3;
      recordedImage3 = null;
    }
  }
  if(i==3) {
    attachments.removeAt(2);
    recordedImage3 = null;
  }
});
```

}

And I observed that the picture actually gets deleted (it will be replaced by a new picture if I click another button to make a photo) but If the user doesn't take another photo the button will not update.

If i long press the first image I get the error but If i press on the last button and make a new picture, the new picture will replace the first image(because it was deleted)

[image]

If you need more details please ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a comment I think, but based on my reputation I am not allowed to do that. Here is what I think is going on:

You have this instruction: `attachments.removeAt(0);` which removes the first element in the list, right before you check the value in `attachments[1]`.

I think you should either check for the length of the array or use `attachements[i] = null` when removing values.

Comment: It seems that I made a mistake in the way I thought when I codded this. It seems that `attachments.removeAt(0)` deletes first value of the list and second element becomes the first and so on. I changed my code from `attachments[1]` (second value which after `attachments.removeAt(0)` becomes the first element meaning `attachments[0]`) to `if(attachments[0] != null)` and no more error